# Regex for IP (v4) address

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to use regex for the IP address from an HTML page:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Current IP Check</title></head>
  <body>Current IP Address: xx.xxx.xxx.xx</body>
</html>
```

And my VB.Net code is currently this:

```
Using wClient As New WebClient
   ip = wClient.DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org/")
   ip = Regex.Match(ip, "^[+-]?(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$", RegexOptions.Singleline).ToString
End Using
```

However, the end results are nothing for IP.

I'm just looking to get **xx.xxx.xxx.xx**

What would I be doing incorrectly?

Comment: Your RegEx assumes that the IP has a whole line to itself which, by example code, it doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regular expression for an IP address is much more complex than you outlined. But there is no reason to re-invent the wheel. Please have a look at [Regular Expression Examples](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html), here is the one that accounts for everything:

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

Answer (score 1):

**vb.net version**

This is for an ipv4 with CIDR notation {example 10.10.10.10/30} and assumes you have a valid IP in your raw data.

It will check the entire text for all matches using MatchCollection instead of just Match for a single instance.

if you only want the first instance in a string, then use Match instead of MatchCollection and you will get only the first occurence.

In that case, I enter some values and pass them in as a list then iterate through each string using a for each loop

Use the other regex in previous answers if you need to make sure the IP is valid as it only goes from 1 to 255 on each octet.

This is simpler if you know you're going to have valid IPs you're trying to isolate with regex from a batch of raw data.

I pass the value of the filtered textbox back to the calling modal form using a Public Property in this form's class which is then referenced in the calling form

```
Public Property ReturnCommands As String = ""

    Private Sub FORM_AddStaticIPsToSR2BNG_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ReturnCommands = ""
End Sub


Private Sub BTN_FilterData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_FilterData.Click
    Dim s As String = TBX_RawData.Text
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(s,"\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[/]\d{1,2}")
    For Each m As Match In matches
        TBX_SR2StaticIPCommands.AppendText("prefix " & m.Value & " type longer" & vbCrLf)
    Next
End Sub
```

' If you know it's a valid IPv4 and doesn't have CIDR notation you would change your regex pattern to "\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}"

Answer (score 0):

IPv4s don't have + or - signs, if you're not in danger of other similar string patterns you can actually do it even more simply

```
\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b
```

Furthermore if you need to find IPv6 addresses then you could try something like

```
\b(?:[\dA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}(?:(?::[\dA-F]{1,4}){1,6}|(?:::[\dA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:|[\dA-F]{1,4})?\b
```

Note that both of these will find "candidates", and shouldn't be used for validation.
If you want to validate IPv6 with RegEx, look [**here**](http://home.deds.nl/~aeron/regex/).

Answer (score 0):

For such simple html you could just use strings.split:

```
Dim source As String = wClient.DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org/")
Dim ip As String = Split(Split(source, "Current IP Address:")(1), "</body>")(0).Trim()
```

Comment: Using string split for parsing HTML is not a good suggestion.

Comment: @Neolisk this was a pragmatic suggestion based on the simplicity of the html in question, which incidentally still works nearly three years later. Regex is equally as fragile, and loading a full on html parser would be overkill for such a trivial situation, though I agree it is the most robust solution

Answer (score 0):

As @Neolisk's answer is worked in most of the time, I edit it to accept number with leading zero:

```
\b(0*(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(0*(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?))\b
```

To accept some IPs like `000010.10.10.000001`